# Corsair Vengeance K-95 Keyboard & Linux

Tags: linux, drivers, keyboard, hardware-compatibility

I've been thinking that I want a mechanical keyboard, currently I'm using a logitech G510 which is perfect with it's 18 programmable keys (I'm using it with [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1421825)) but I hear a lot of people drooling over mechanical keys, especially programmers, and I do certainly write a lot and on occasion I code too. Not to mention gaming of course.

But one thing I really cannot think of losing is the 18(x3) programmables, I don't care about the rest of the features, but being able to open folders, switch workspaces and navigate through my browser with single buttons changes everything. Not to mention it is very efficient.

Media keys are also always nice (Play/Pause, Volume wheel)

The [Corsair Vengeance K-95](http://www.corsair.com/en/vengeance-k95-fully-mechanical-gaming-keyboard-uk-key-layout) was the first keyboard I found that seems to match my needs.

1. Does it work with Linux? (If so, how well?)
2. Can I map custom commands (like terminal commands) to the G keys?

Comment: Media keys have standard USB HID codes, which have long been recognized by Linux, so they should Just Work.  As for the custom keys, there is no standard for this; every keyboard with custom keys does it differently.  You may have to ask Corsair if they provide programming specs for the Linux crowd.  At the very least, you'll want to blink all those individual LEDs...

Comment: @ewhac well corsair don't seem to take mails unless I register at theirs. I don't like registering all over the place just to ask some simple question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This keyboard doesn't work properly on Linux. The entire keyboard freezes if you press any macro key.

To be more precise, a kernel issue is currently in progress<sup>[1]</sup>, and a userpace driver is available with some limitations<sup>[2]</sup>.

- [1] *[Bug 79251 - Keyboard status indicators not functioning properly.](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=79251)*
- [2] *[K70/K95 RGB (Unofficial) Linux Driver](http://forum.corsair.com/v3/showthread.php?t=133929)*

Comment: +1 I have a new K95 RGB and I'm typing on it in Linux. I absolutely LOVE the keyboard.. but the keyboard does completely freeze when I press any macro key. In order to get it working again, I have to unplug and replug (and the computer's on the other side of the room!) I pulled off the keycaps on the macro keys to keep from accidentally hitting them and hope they get a firmware update very soon. (Unfortunately, don't even know if I'll be able to update from a windows VM... what's wrong with dd if=newfirmware of=/dev/mykeyboard? C'mon Corsair, what's going on here?!) If not, this is going back.

Comment: Do the media keys work on it? I'm thinking about buying it anyways and seeing what I can do to help develop the community driver.

As for updating firmware through a VM, you should be able to do it by using passthrough, but a firmware update can be a kind of sensitive procedure so you probalby don't wanna take any chances with that.

Comment: yes, media key work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

First question: will it work? The answer is yes, it will work, but not as you would want it.

You can have it work like a normal keyboard, but when it comes to the second question the answer is no. You will probably not get it to work with Linux because for now Corsair has not released Linux drivers. By searching the forums I found out that other people were trying to work this problem too and with no success.

Comment: That partially answers my question yes, it was obvious that it would work like a normal keyboard, but some links to those forum sources of yours would be nice though.

Comment: Here for example is one [link]http://forum.corsair.com/v3/showthread.php?t=109501. Eventough its K90 keyboard it still has similar drivers and capabilities to use the g-keys.

Comment: That's very old (3.4.5, 2012), but thanks that answers my question as it is indeed a similar keyboard.